# How to change user eMail field markup from preprocess function

Tags: 8

I want to change the markup of the user's email field before it is getting printed.
Since there is a lot of logic I need to include, I want to change it from a preprocess function rather than twig.

Which preprocess function should I use and how would I change the field value?

Comment: When using `hook_preprocess`, the *render array* (the "Drupal thing" that contains the rendered HTML output along with meta information like cache tags) has already been created and most likely turned into a single string. At this point it is quite hard to do changes any changes on anything beyond the wrapping HTML tag or the field label. Instead create your own custom module with a field formatter.  I found this [blog post](https://www.ryanbateman.space/2019/10/tutorial-writing-field-formatters-for-drupal-8/) quite useful.

Comment: There are wider [docs on d.o](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-1), but this is only needed for advanced tools like settings form for your field formatter, IMHO the blog post above is easier to understand.

Comment: @Hudri 
I very much like the field formatter idea. Thank you!!